# get current logged user on Plone

Tags: python, plone

I would like to get the 'location' (an attribute, like username, user id, ...) of current logged user in my plone instance.

To get the current user I've tried:

```
from AccessControl import getSecurityManager
user = getSecurityManager().getUser()
username = user.getUserName()
```

But for both user and username I get the string "System Processes"

How can I solve this?

**edit**

I've tried

```
from plone import api
user = api.user.get_current()
user.getProperty('location')
```

but I get:

> CannotGetPortalError: Unable to get the portal object.

Comment: What do you mean by 'location' here? What is the configuration of your PAS (Pluggable Authentication Setup)? How do users log in to your Plone site?

Comment: I've edited the question. Users login with the standard platform login.

Comment: What does `print type(user), repr(user)` produce?

Comment: <class 'AccessControl.users.UnrestrictedUser'>
<UnrestrictedUser 'System Processes'>

Comment: Right, that is the `system` user, the *User that passes all security checks*. This *can* also be the emergency user (defined in the `access` file in your instance directory).

Comment: ok, and what about the logged user? How can I get his attributes?

Comment: Is this applied for **all** logins?

Comment: I've added those lines of code in my plugin (available for all users) I logged with a user that is not an administrator: the output is the one I posted

Comment: Do you have a `access` file in your `var/instance` directory? Does this happen for *other* logins?

Comment: Yes I do and yes it happens with all logins

Comment: So what happens when you **remove** that file (rename it temporarily and restart).

Comment: In that case the instance can't run

Comment: The `access` file is normally **optional**. What is the error message you get in that case?

Comment: maybe there is a misunderstanding: what file I have to rename? The 'instance' folder?

Comment: I am talking about a file named `access` *inside* the `instance` folder.

Comment: Sorry. I haven't any 'access' file in var/instance

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread some code; you have the `system` user, not the `emergency_user` object. **Why** you have the system user is not clear however. It is not the user that logged in here. You'll need to show more context as to how the code you posted is called. The system user has no interesting properties you can show, really.

Comment: If you are dipping your toes into Zope/Plone development, it might help if you try again using a minimum buildout-based instance.  https://github.com/collective/minimalplone4 could be a useful starting point.  Build yourself a completely fresh instance and see if this problem persist, if you were unable to figure out what caused this and if the problem itself is unimportant.

Comment: Huh, just realized one more thing I forgot to ask: are you doing this under the `debug` shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution [here](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/To-get-Current-Logged-username-code-is-working-in-zpt-views-but-the-same-code-is-not-working-in-Plon-td3646748.html).

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

membership = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_membership')
authenticated_user = membership.getAuthenticatedMember().getProperty('location') 
print authenticated_user
```

Answer (score 3):

I would advise using plone.api here. You can do the following:

```
from plone import api
user = api.user.get_current()
user.getProperty('location')
```

Comment: I forgot to write that I also tried this solution but I get: *plone unable get portal object*

Comment: The OP has not got a 'regular' user object, they have the *system user*, so there are no properties either.

Answer (score 1):

**self.context** must be called in a class method. In a simple python scritp use just **context**. This script works

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName 
mt = getToolByName(context, 'portal_membership') 
if  mt.isAnonymousUser(): 
    member = 'anonymous' 
else:
    member = mt.getAuthenticatedMember() 

print member
return printed
```